# Eloquent hasOneThrough relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Currently my database setup looks like this:

Users table (User model):

- id,
- email

Discounts table (Coupon model)

- code
- amount

Now, I decided to create a pivot table, where I will store a discount value for a user. One user will have a single discount value. For this, I created `PractitionerVoucher` model with this table setup:

- voucher_id
- practitioner_id

Upon creating a Coupon record, I save the `coupon_id` (`voucher_id` in this case) and the `user_id` (`practitioner_id` in this case) values to `PractitionerVoucher` table. Now, my question is, how do I get the User record from the Coupon model? For example:

```
$coupon = Coupon::first();
$coupon->practitioner;
```

I tried to create `hasOneThrough` relation on `Coupon` model, but no luck so far. This is what I tried:

```
public function practitioner(){
  return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, PractitionerVoucher::class, 'practitioner_id', 'id');
}
```

Using this relation, I get no query results for the `User` model. This is how my database records look like:

Coupons table
[image]

PractitionerVoucher table:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This isn't the correct table structure or use case for hasOneThrough. You can just use a hasMany and then just call `first()` on the end

Comment: Or just out the discount_id in the user table and use a hasOne

Comment: hasOneThrough would require an id in the discount table, but it doesn't really make sense for this instance

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be easily done by adding a **coupon_id** column on **users** table and defining a **One-to-Many** relationship between **User** and **Coupon** model - there's no need for a pivot table.

On **User** model

```php
public function discount()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Coupon::class, 'coupon_id');
}
```

On **Coupon** model

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Then you can use the relationship

```php
$coupon = Coupon::with('users')->first();
$coupon->users;
```